# Excel: Combine Multiple Columns into New Sheet without Column Names

Tags: vba, excel

The code I have below combines multiple columns from one Worksheet into a new / existing (named `MasterList`) into one column.

The issue that I am having is that every column has a column name that is getting placed into the new worksheet. The column names are always found in row 1.

```
Sub ToArrayAndBack()
Dim arr As Variant, lLoop1 As Long, lLoop2 As Long
Dim arr2 As Variant, lIndex As Long

'turn off updates to speed up code execution
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With

ReDim arr2(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells.Count - ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count)

arr = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value


For lLoop1 = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
    For lLoop2 = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
        If Len(Trim(arr(lLoop1, lLoop2))) > 0 Then
            arr2(lIndex) = arr(lLoop1, lLoop2)
            lIndex = lIndex + 1
        End If
    Next
Next

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim found As Boolean
found = False
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If ws.Name = "MasterList" Then
        found = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next
If Not found Then
    Sheets.Add.Name = "MasterList"
End If

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MasterList")
With ws
     .Range("A1").Resize(, lIndex + 1).Value = arr2

     .Range("A1").Resize(, lIndex + 1).Copy
     .Range("A2").Resize(lIndex + 1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
     .Rows(1).Delete
End With

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .DisplayAlerts = True
End With


End Sub
```

To recap I want to use this code to combine multiple columns from one worksheet into another without column names.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Resize(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count-1,ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Offset(1,0)
```

This should do the trick